# Why does e1071 give me NAs for this Naive Bayes classifier predictions?

Tags: r

**FAILS**

```
library(e1071)

train.x <- data.frame(
  B=c(0,1,0),
  C=c(0,0,0),
  D=c(0,0,1),
  Z=c(1,0,0)
)

classifier <- naiveBayes(x=train.x, y=factor(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)), laplace=1)  # use laplace (i.e. alpha) of nearly 0
predict(classifier, train.x, type="raw")

     FALSE TRUE
[1,]    NA   NA
[2,]    NA   NA
[3,]    NA   NA
```

**WORKS**

```
train.x <- data.frame(
  B=c(0,1,0,1),
  C=c(0,0,0,1),
  D=c(0,0,1,1),
  Z=c(1,0,0,1)
)

classifier <- naiveBayes(x=train.x, y=factor(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)), laplace=1)  # use laplace (i.e. alpha) of nearly 0
predict(classifier, train.x, type="raw")

              FALSE           TRUE
[1,] 0.000000002761 0.999999997239
[2,] 0.000000002761 0.999999997239
[3,] 0.997729292055 0.002270707945
[4,] 0.999999994295 0.000000005705
```

Seems as though this only works if there are at least two TRUE *and* two FALSE cases.

Comment: My guess is: there may be something to do with # independent variables > #training examples in the first case.

Answer (score 0):

For numeric variables, `naiveBayes` uses the mean and standard deviation of each variable to calculate the probability of each variable for each class. Since you have only three training examples, the standard deviation of at least one class must be undefined (the class for which you have provided two training examples is fine). You can see that by looking at the `tables` attribute of your classifier, which show mean and standard deviation:

```
> classifier$tables
$B
                            B
factor(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)) [,1]      [,2]
                       FALSE  0.0        NA
                       TRUE   0.5 0.7071068

$C
                            C
factor(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)) [,1] [,2]
                       FALSE    0   NA
                       TRUE     0    0

$D
                            D
factor(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)) [,1] [,2]
                       FALSE    1   NA
                       TRUE     0    0

$Z
                            Z
factor(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)) [,1]      [,2]
                       FALSE  0.0        NA
                       TRUE   0.5 0.7071068
```

`naiveBayes` differentiates between *numeric* and *categorical* variables, and the probability for categorical variables works without the standard deviation. So, if you convert your data to *logical*, it works:

```
train.x <- sapply(train.x, as.logical)
classifier <- naiveBayes(x=train.x, y=factor(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)), laplace=1)
predict(classifier, train.x, type="raw")
         FALSE       TRUE
[1,] 0.4705882 0.52941176
[2,] 0.4705882 0.52941176
[3,] 0.9142857 0.08571429
```

So, yes, at least two examples per class are necessary. Unless you use categorical variables.